# How do I remove brackets from IEEE citations in Microsoft Word?

Tags: microsoft-word

I wanted to create a custom template without the brackets (e.g. IEEE citations look like this: [1] [2] [3] etc.). I want my references to look like this instead: 1 2 3 (no brackets surrounding the numbers).

The below guide shows how to do it (very easily) in APA format.

https://www.officetooltips.com/word_2016/tips/change_the_type_of_brackets_in_citations.html

Unfortunately, this does not work on the IEEE style template (does the IEEE style template even use the OpenBracket and CloseBracket templates? I'm starting to think it doesn't. It creates them and then never references them anywhere else).

Any help? I feel like this shouldn't be this hard, but I don't see an easy way to do this with Word.

Edit: Found it! Instead of following the instructions for the OpenBracket and CloseBracket templates in the provided guide, you need to do it for the SecondaryOpen and SecondaryClose templates (the non-APA ones). The problem is that this changes some things in the Bibliography too, so it doesn't work right. I think I might need to create a new template in the sheet and find out where the citation reference calls that template and just change it to the new template.

Comment: You haven't removed the brackets. Your XML still contains parentheses. `<xsl:text>(</xsl:text>` and `<xsl:text>)</xsl:text>` You could try replacing both of those lines with `<xsl:text></xsl:text>`

Comment: @DavidPostill I tried that, but I can't get the brackets to change to parenthesis like in the code you showed above and removing the parenthesis has no effect either. I always get square brackets. Does it work for you?

Comment: No idea - I don't use Word :)

Comment: You might have to create a custom citation style to achieve exactly what you want. There are some useful links for this at the end of my answer [IEEE 2006 Citation style puts comma inside quotation marks in bibliography](//superuser.com/a/1172958)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, figured this out. It's different than the APA style, which is why the guide didn't work. Here's what you do:

1. Find your style files storage location (it's usually C:\Users(insert username here)\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Bibliography\Style
2. Copy and paste your IEEE template file and rename the copy something like customtemplate or whatever
3. Open the customtemplate style file in notepad and press ctrl+h type in IEEE and replace the text with something memorable like customtemplate. This renames the template so it shows up in word.
4. Search for "templ_prop_SecondaryClose" and go to the end of that template (should be like ).
5. Paste in the below (creates another template to reference)

(this is needed to show the code for some reason)

```
<xsl:template name="templ_prop_CitationOpen" >
    <xsl:param name="LCID" />
    <xsl:variable name="_LCID">
        <xsl:call-template name="localLCID">
            <xsl:with-param name="LCID" select="$LCID"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:value-of select="/*/b:Locals/b:Local[@LCID=INITIAL_CONTENTLCID]/b:APA/b:CitationOpen"/>
<xsl:text></xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="templ_prop_CitationClose" >
    <xsl:param name="LCID" />
    <xsl:variable name="_LCID">
        <xsl:call-template name="localLCID">
            <xsl:with-param name="LCID" select="$LCID"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:value-of select="/*/b:Locals/b:Local[@LCID=INITIAL_CONTENTLCID]/b:APA/b:CitationClose"/>
<xsl:text></xsl:text>
</xsl:template>
```

6. Now, just search for secondaryopen and replace the last one in the IEEE file (AND ONLY THE LAST ONE) with CitationOpen
7. search for secondaryclose and replace the last one in the IEEE file (AND ONLY THE LAST ONE) with CitationClose
8. Save file, open word, you should now have access to this reference style